# Pandas how to check row is from which dataframe when comparing 2 dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code which compares 2 columns in 2 dataframes, which actually returns the rows which are different in both dataframes but I want to get the rows which are different for example in `df1` not in both:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([('a','b','src'), ('a','b','src'), ('c','b','src'),('a','d','src')],columns=['col1','col2','origin'])
df2 = df1.copy(deep=True)
df2['origin'] = 'tgt'
df1['col1'][3] = 't'
df2['col2'][2] = 't'
df1[(df1['col1'] != df2['col1']) | (df1['col2'] != df2['col2'])]
```

which gives output as in the image:
[image]

Now, over here I do see the 2 differences but the origin column is always `src`. What I want is, the count of rows which are different but only from source i.e. `df1`

Comment: what isyour expected output

Comment: Can you add [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: I edited the question, please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

Because same columns and same indices in both `DataFrame`s, is possible compare between them.

For check not equal in `df1` and also in `df2` need `sum` of `True`s in boolean mask:

```
mask = (df1['col1'] != df2['col1']) | (df1['col2'] != df2['col2'])
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool

out = mask.sum()
print (out)
2
```

Comment: This gives count of rows which are not equal in both but what I want is the count of rows which are different but in `df1` not in `df2`, i.e. 1

Comment: @FaizanAli - Can you explain more how you get `1` from sample data?

Comment: `df1['col1'][3] = 't' ` that is one difference but from `df1` .  `df2['col2'][2] = 't'` that is one difference but from `df2`. Your answer is `2` since the difference is counted from both df's but I want the one from `df1`.

Comment: @FaizanAli - Sorry, I dont understand, how is possible know what values are in `df1` not equal with `df2` and `df2` not equal with `df1` ? I think it is same. Or not?